# Refresh Menu Items onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using support library. In actionbar i have a huge logo (width = 320), searchView and few menu items(like favorites, etc).
Also, my activity uses onConfigurationChanged.

The problem is the following :
After i rotate the device, ActionMenuView does not recalculate its width. It uses the same space, as in previous orientation.

So if i start activity in protrait mode, and ActionMenuView gets 250px for width, it will occupy 250px width in landscape mode too.

If i start activity in landscape mode and ActionMenuView gets 450px for width, it will occupy 450px width in portrait mode too !

Here i got 3 issues, connected with this problem.

1. The number of menuItems with "asRoom" parameter depends not on current orientation, but on start orientation of activity. If 3 items are hidden in overflow menu and 2 are visible from the start of activity, it will be the same after rotating. But if we start activity in another orientation, we'll get another number of hidden menuItems from start, and this number will not change until we re-create this activity.
2. If we use custom home button drawable with ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator, ActionMenuView does not understand how much space should it occupy. If we start activity in landscape mode - ActionMenuView occupy a lot of space. And after we rotate the device - it will try to draw itself out of the screen.
3. Different Logo size. If we start from portrait, ActionMenuView does understands that there is not so much place for it. It occupy small area, and logo has normal size even after rotationg. But if we start from landscap, ActionMenuView occupies a lot of space. And it is still trying to get the same amount of area after the rotation. That is why logo's size is reduced.

How can i explain to the ActionMenuView that it should recalculate its limited width after the rotation ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question in the following approach :

In OnConfigurationChanged method recreate Menu in the following way

```
ActionMenuPresenter presenter = new ActionMenuPresenter(getActivity());
MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(getActivity());
menuBuilder.setCallback(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
        onOptionsItemSelected(arg1);
        return false;
    }
});
toolbar.setMenu(menuBuilder, presenter);
```

But, when we use custom Menu object - it loses styles. I use AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar theme, but my overflow menu button and search widget text become black (instead of white) after i rotate device and recreate menu.

I fix it by customizing search widget in xml file with white icons for search and clear, programmatically setting textColor + hintTextColor to white, and declaring following style for my overflow menu button :

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">#FFF</item>
</style>
```